# Compute $\sum_{m>n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!n!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

Compute the series

$$\sum_{m>n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!n!}$$

Comment: I don't understand the notation. What is the range of $m$? Is $n$ a paramenter or is that a double summation over $n$, and $m$?

Comment: Presumably means $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{  m!n!}$$?

Comment: @Bambi: Yes, it may be rewritten the way you wrote it above.

Comment: @leonbloy: see Bambi's comment. I wrote it the way I received it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{  m!\,n!} = \left(\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}+ \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots\right)=(e-1)^2$$
We must substract from that the "diagonal" terms: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^2 = I_0(2) - 1 \approx 2.2795853-1$$ ([ref](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html) ; $I_0(\cdot)$  is the modified Bessel function of the first kind) and divide by two to get the desired region. Hence the result is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{  m!\,n!}=\frac{(e-1)^2 - (I_0(2)-1)}{2}= \frac{e^2-I_0}{2}+1-e \approx 0.83645357$$

Comment: (+1) Thanks! I didn't think it's so easy (or you made it look that easy) excepting the fact that there is nothing told about the way you got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^2 = I_0(2) - 1 \approx 2.2795853-1$.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: That part is not at all easy, for me at least. I only managed to reduce the double series to a plain series, which, fortunately, I found  tabulated :-)

Comment: understood! It's OK! :-)